# Unrecognized Login Screen

Tags: 16.04

I've been using Ubuntu for years,currently run 16.04 LTS. When I finish a session on computer, I lock down with GUFW and turn the monitor off. Several times lately,when I turn on the monitor, I see a login screen that I don't think I've seen before. (see screenshot) Anyone have an idea of where this is coming from? Thanks for any insights.

[image: Login Screen]

Comment: Does it show anything interesting when you enter a wrong password?

Comment: Don't know... I don't try to log in with that screen. When I turn the monitor on, I see the usual request for a password, which I enter. Once at the desktop, that's when I see the bogus login screen.

Comment: Could it be a Dropbox login?

Comment: I've never used Dropbox, so I tend to doubt that's what it is.

Comment: I had that on Lubuntu on 16.04, where a bug prevented the system from unlocking the keyring when I logged in. Try running seahorse (you might have to install it first) and see if you get the same error message. Let us know what happens.

Comment: Thanks, Paddy, you might have nailed it. Ran Seahorse, found a couple of entries that related to login to sync a google calendar set up through Evolution. I had removed Evolution several weeks ago; ran a purge on it, and haven't seen that login screen since. Looking good so far; time will tell. Thanks all for the input.